# stop windows service on an event

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I need to stop the service on an event .where i am sending file through ftp and ftp response is generating in text file.
So i am checking the response in text file ,if failoure message is there then i need to stop the service.But because this one is not an exception so i am not able to call OnStart method where i can stop the service.
How to stop the service in class?

```
Dim text As String = "Error: Could not open connection"
Dim lines() As String = Filter(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SFtpLogFullPath), text)

If UBound(lines) = -1 Then
    'MsgBox("not found")
Else
    'MsgBox("found")
    Dim UpdFailFTPStatus As New AseCommand("update tb_kamp_filesprocess set FileFTPStatus = '" & "" & "' where FILENAME = '" & fileName & "' ", _SQLConnection)
    recordsAffected = UpdFailFTPStatus.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ExecuteSP("ml_test_kamp")
    writelog("Error occured during SFTP ")
    'Need to stop the service here
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: How did you start the service?

Comment: @preciousbetine i start the service "OnStart" method

Comment: You need to call service.OnStop();

Comment: @user3344236 OnStop() calling only if exception is coming.and i need to stop the service on an event where a specific file created.